# From master, commit to another branch

Tags: git, github

I usually create branches for the different segments of code but once in a while I forget to create a new branch and everything is happening on the master branch.

How can I say to git that although I am on the master branch, this commit is for the `xyz` branch?

Comment: What is your `fascination` with having certain `words` in monospace?

Comment: Much easier to read and stay focused on the question

Comment: @PNY: backticks are for code. Don't use them on regular words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just checkout that branch first and commit to it

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
# `git add` what you need
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already committed on master one which should go on another branch, you can;

```
# create a branch on that commit
git branch mynewbranch
# reset master to the previous commit
# git reset --hard HEAD~
```

(Make sure you don't have any private file not added yet to the index, or the `reset --hard` would erase them: you can use `git stash` to save them temporarily)

Then you can switch on `mynewbranch` is you have other commits to do on that new branch:

```
git checkout mynewbranch
```